# Displaying message on a successful unit test in Matlab

Tags: matlab, unit-testing

Is there a way to display a message when a unit test passes. Such as what it was testing.

I know I can show a message when it fails to pass

```
function testOne (testCase)
% some test here
msg = 'This will show what it fails';
             testCase.assertEqual(properties(Object), expProp, msg);  
end
```

Comment: Isn't it just enough to use `disp` after assertion? Otherwise you can listen to `AssertionPassed` event of [TestCase](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.testcase-class.html).

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on kyamagu's comment, assuming you are using R2014a you can write a listener that listens to AssertionPassed events. This listener is a function that take the source object (the TestCase instance) and an [event data](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.qualifications.qualificationeventdata-class.html) instance which contains information about the assertion like the actual value, the constraint used, and diagnsotics passed by the user. If you are doing this for one test you can jsut add this listener directly inside the test

```
methods(Test)
    function testOne (testCase)
        testCase.addlistener('AssertionPassed', ...
            @(src,evd) disp('This will show what it succeeds'));

        % some test here
        msg = 'This will show what it fails';
        testCase.assertEqual(properties(Object), expProp, msg);  
    end
end
```

If you want to show something about the success for every single assertion or verification, you may be able to get what you want by [writing your own plugin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/write-plugins-to-extend-testrunner.html). Plugins get handed the correct TestCase instances and can use them to add these listeners for both passing and failing qualifications. Once you write a plugin, you can install it onto a TestRunner and be able to get the desired behavior for all assertions, verifications, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What about helpdlg?

```
function testOne (testCase)
% some test here, result is boolean in variable Test
if Test
msg = 'This will show what it succeeds';
helpdlg(msg);
else
msg = 'This will show what it fails';
testCase.assertEqual(properties(Object), expProp, msg);  
end
end
```

You could add a timer for it to disappear after a certain amount of time... Also disp is a solution if it's for inline commands...